# Executing a LINQPad query from the command line and closing LINQPad afterwards

Tags: linqpad

I have found out how to run and execute a LINQPad query from the command line by using the following command

```
LINQPad.exe "path to the script.linq" -run
```

This will launch LINQPad, run the script but it leaves LINQPad open.  Is there anyway that I can get LINQPad to close after execution?

Many thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported at present, but full command-line functionality should be available within a month or so via a new lprun.exe tool that will ship with LINQPad. The tool will be free, and will support text, JSON and HTML output.

**Edit:** This is now available: http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx